# How to stop getting notification on every launch of application in android?

Tags: android, notifications, alarm

in my application I have set the notification inside onCreate() of launcher activity. I am getting result successfully but as it is written inside the onCreate it is showing notification every time I launch app also.
How should I resolve this, I want the notification only on given time.
Below is the code I am using :-

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 49);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Main.this, MyReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Main.this, 0, myIntent,0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new method and call the method when you want your notification to launch.

```
public void showNotification() {

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 49);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Main.this, MyReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Main.this, 0, myIntent,0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

}
```

Now when you want to call this method simple write:

```
showNotification();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey I tried but it's not working. . :-( Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you trying to call it yourself or when a certain time has been met or passed for example?

Comment: hey I did it by comparing system current time and time I set. . Thanks for your help. :-)